# How to validate email is real or fake in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rubygems

I have a problem I need write validator in rails to checking an email is real or fake? I try to research but nothing. Can someone help me? Thanks !

Comment: https://github.com/kickboxio/kickbox-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ruby gem to handle for checking email is real or fake. Awesome, it support validate for model.

https://github.com/minhquan4080/email_detected

Answer (score 2):

Use 2-factor email authentication method.

Send email to user email address and verify it.

Its the best method to validate email.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option:
1. Best one is You can send a confirmation mail to user to confirm its genuine user or not?

2. Use `gem 'email_validator' , require: 'email_validator/strict'` to validate email

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/OpenGems/rails_email_checker

Checks MX records, sub address, regex, whitelisted and blacklisted check